# How to convert On Action Execution from .net to .net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am converting my .net application to .net core and have come across a few errors. 
can i please know on how to resolve the on Action execution as well as the URL error. 
Can I please get your help to resolve them. [image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Changing the access modifier of a method in a derived type is not allowed. You should change protected to public.

2.The HttpRequest object is different in ASP.NET Core. It no longer contains Url property.

By using:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

then you can get the full http request url by executing:

```
HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
```